# When can't computation speed be improved by parallelization?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find an answer that was more about the low level mechanics of threads themselves.

**Problem**

I have a physical modeling project in which I need to apply a function to 160 billion data points.

```
for(int i=0; i < N(160,000,000,000); i++){
     physicalModal(input[i]); //Linear function, just additions and subtractions
}
function physicalModal(x){
A*x +B*x +C*x + D*x......... //An over simplification but you get the idea. A linear function
}
```

Given the nature of this problem am I correct in thinking a single thread on a single core, or 1 thread per core, would be the fastest way to solve this? That using extra threads beyond the number of cores would not help me here?

**My Logic (Please correct where my assumptions are wrong)**

Threads on a single core don't really work independently, they just share processor time which can be beneficial when one thread is waiting on perhaps a socket response and other threads are processing requests. In the example I posted above I figure the CPU could go to 100% on one thread so using multiple threads would just disturb the computation. Is this correct?

**What then determines when threading is useful?**

If my above assumption is correct, whats the key factor in determining when other threads would be useful? My guess would be simultaneous operations that have varying completion times, waiting, etc...But thats based on my initial premise which may be incorrect.

Comment: isn't this dependent on hardware? Some cores have 8 threads, some 2, some 40+. Some cores context switch in 1000 cycles, some switch per 2 cycles. but your code seems embarassingly parallel so 1 thread per work item should be fine imho

Comment: Threads will be useful when there are several cores (this era is manycore era) and/or when some threads may block on some resource like socket or file reading from disk. In first case - 1 thread per core is correct (2 threads per physical core when there is Hyper-Threading or other SMT; use OpenMP/MPI); in second you may use several threads per core.

Comment: @osgx cool. So would you say my best bet is throw more CPUs at this? That was my original plan; to slice the list of inputs into X number of lists and have the equation run on multiple machines concurrently, each probably having Z number of cores so I'd spawn a thread per core on each machine but I wanted to be sure I'm taking full advantage of a single machine before I throw in another.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil, you should check that single-thread code works good (for linear function it can be possible to use SIMD on input elements, we can say more if you post more code), then just apply OpenMP for thread parallelism (add `#pragma omp parallel for` before your for loop if it is C/C++). OpenMP runtime library will select number of threads (or you can set it) and will split iteration between threads. You should check that `physicalModal` iterations are independent and there is no any global variables (post more code and more specific question).

Comment: @osgx Thanks. The physical modeling coding has no globals. Its a series of equations which I'm still working on but you can think them as polynomials. No special internal data structures,state or side effects. A pure function in functional programming sense. But I think you've given me enough to explore.

Comment: When you can entirely avoid blocking on I/O (whether due to page faults, file reads, or whatever), one thread per core is usually best. When you can't, you may benefit from having an extra thread or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to apply a function to 160 billion data points.

I assume that your function has no side effects (no writes to global/static variables; no disk/network access; no service to many remote users) and just do some arithmetics on its input (on single point of input or several nearby points as for [stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_(numerical_analysis)) (it is [stencil kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code)):

```
for(int i=0; i < 160_000_000_000; i++){
     //Linear function, just additions and subtractions 
     output[i] = physicalModel(input[i] /* possibly also input[i-1], input[i+1] .. */); 
}
```

Then you have to check how efficient this function works on single CPU. Can you (or your compiler) [unroll your loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) and convert it to [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) parallelism?

```
for(int i=0+1; i < 160_000_000_000-1; i++){
    output[i] = A*input[i-1]+ B*input[i] + C*input[i+1];
}
// unrolled 4 times; if input is float, compiler may load 4 floats 
// into single SSE2 reg and do 4 operations from one asm command
for(int i=0+4; i < 160_000_000_000-4; i+=4){
    output[i+0] = A*input[i-1]+ B*input[i+0] + C*input[i+1];
    output[i+1] = A*input[i+0]+ B*input[i+1] + C*input[i+2];
    output[i+2] = A*input[i+1]+ B*input[i+2] + C*input[i+3];
    output[i+3] = A*input[i+2]+ B*input[i+3] + C*input[i+4];
}
```

When your function has good single-threaded performance, you can add thread or process parallelism (using OpenMP/MPI or other method). With our assumptions, there are no threads blocking on some external resource like reading from HDD or from network, so every thread you started can run at any time. Then we should start no more than 1 thread per CPU core. If we started several threads, each will run for some amount of time and displaced by other, having less performance than in case of 1 thread per cpu core.

In C/C++ adding of OpenMP thread level parallelism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP, http://www.openmp.org/) can be as easy as adding one line just before your for loop (and [adding `-fopenmp`/`-openmp` option](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_openmp/compile_run.html) to your compilation); compiler and library will split your for loop into parts and distribute them between threads ([0..N/4], [N/4..N/2], [N/2..N*3/4], [N*3/4..N] for 4 threads or other split scheme; you can give hints with [schedule option](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html))

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0+1; i < 160_000_000_000-1; i++){
    output[i] = physicalModel(input[i]);;
}
```

Thread count will be determined in runtime by OpenMP library (gomp in gcc - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/index.html). By default [it is "one thread per CPU is used"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS.html#OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS) (per logical cpu core). You can change number of threads with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable (`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=5; ./program`).

On CPU with hardware multithreading on single cpu cores (Intel HT, other variants of SMT: you have 4 physical cores and 8 "logical") in some cases you should use 1 thread per logical core, and in other cases 1 thread per physical core (with correct thread binding), as some resources (FPU units) [are shared between logical cores](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=6&v=t). Do some experiments if your code will be used several (many) times.

If your threads (model) are limited by speed of memory (Memory Bound; they loads many data from memory and does very simple operation on every float), you may want to run less threads than cpu core count, as additional threads will not get addition memory bandwidth.

If your threads do lot of computations for every element loaded from memory, use better SIMD and more threads (compute bound). When you have very good and wide SIMD (full-width AVX), you will have no speedup from using HT, as full-width AVX unit is shared between logical cores (but every physical core has one, so use it); in this case you will also have lower cpu frequency, as full-width AVX unit is very hot under full load.

Illustration of memory and compute limited applications: https://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/

https://crd.lbl.gov/assets/Uploads/FTG/Projects/Roofline/_resampled/ResizedImage600300-rooflineai.png

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil, any additional questions or examples of real code? What is ratio of bytes read from caches/memory to flops in your model?

Comment: The example you put forth is close enough to what I would actually do which is why I accepted the answer. All that would differ would be me showing the actual coefficients and full equation which I'm still writing. Thanks for the Fourier analysis bit as well.